# Exact sequence of graded modules and localization

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules

I know that a sequence of modules is exact iff the localization at each prime ideal is exact

What happens in the case we are working with graded modules? Can we say that a sequence is exact iff the localization at each homogeneous prime ideal is exact?

Comment: As far as I remember, the answer is yes, but I have no reference at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes and the reason is that the functor $-\otimes R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is faithfully exact in the category of graded $R$-modules; this is Proposition 1.5.15(c) in Bruns and Herzog.

In the above notation $R$ is our graded ring and it is assumed that it has a unique homogeneous ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, which is maximal with respect to all other homogeneous ideals, i.e., $R$ is $^*$local in the terminology of Bruns and Herzog.

Comment: So this is only true when the ring is local?

Comment: This is true when the ring is what Bruns and Herzog call $*$local, i.e., there is a unique maximal homogeneous ideal. I don't know what happens for more general rings.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the *. Well it works for me. Thanks!